# Why is this code segment marked dead code?

Tags: java, dead-code

For the life of me, I can't see why Eclipse is marking the `else if` clause below as "dead code":

```
BaType rbName = rSoapXml.getName().getBName();
BaType cbName = cSoapXml.getName().getBName();
IaType riName = rSoapXml.getName().getIName();
IaType ciName = cSoapXml.getName().getIName();

String rbNameF = rbName.getF() == null ? "null" : rbName.getF();
String cbNameF = (cbName == null || cbName.getF() == null) ? "null" : cbName.getF();
LOG.info("\n***BEFORE***: " + rbNameF + ", COM: " + cbNameF);

if (cbName != null) {
  if (riName != null) {
    String errMsg = "Expected an I message but received a B instead.";
    throw new RuntimeException(errMsg);               
  }
  if (cbName.getBorE() != null)
    rbName.setBorE(cbName.getBorE());
  if (rbName.getBorE() == null && cbName.getBorE() == null) {
    String errMsg = "Missing B name!";
    throw new RuntimeException(errMsg);               
  }
}
else if (ciName != null) {                                               // dead
  if (rbName != null) {                                                  // dead  
    String errMsg = "Expected a B message but received an I instead.";   // dead
    throw new RuntimeException(errMsg);                                  // dead
  }                                                                      // dead
  if (ciName.getIName() != null)                                         // dead
    riName.setIName(ciName.getIName());                                  // dead
  if (riName.getIName() == null && ciName.getIName() == null) {          // dead
    String errMsg = "Missing I name";                                    // dead
    throw new RuntimeException(errMsg);                                  // dead 
  }

}
```

Points I have considered:

1. ciName is initialized at runtime and cannot be guaranteed to be non-null.
2. cbName is not guaranteed to be non-null either, hence the `else` following its check should be valid.

What am I missing here?

Comment: probably because cbName is never null therefore it will not run the else if

Comment: Possible that `cSoapXml.getName().getBName()` is annotated with `@NotNull` (if this is possible :D), therefore `cbName` can never be null.

Comment: @j.con Thanks! I have suspected that but I am not sure how Eclipse know that. Is it because an accessor method that returns a String can never return a null?

Comment: probably returns an empty string `""` or a `"null"`

Comment: @Tom I just checked and it's **not** annotated with `@NotNull`. However, the entire class is annotated `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`.

Comment: BTW, based on some NullPointerExpections I received while testing, `rbName.getF()` can be null. That is why I placed the check before the LOG statement. It is the same type of an `@XmlAccessorType` (also a String). Weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is wrong and this should probably be considered an Eclipse compiler bug. Normally, the compiler will conclude you are dereferencing a variable earlier on, which makes sure that later in the code the variable is non-null. It probably got confused by this line:

```
String cbNameF = (cbName == null || cbName.getF() == null) ? "null" : cbName.getF();
```

It seems like you dereference `cbName` here, but you actually deference it only if it is *not* null. The variable may legally be `null` at the point where you check it and the `else` branch is not dead.

If you are compiling with Eclipse, then cross-check with the reference compiler (`javac`).

Comment: I think you are right. I just added a general `else` and it is marked dead as well, so the problem isn't with the `else if (ciName != null)` but rather with `if (cbName != null)`. I know it can be null (see comment above), so my only conclusion is that Eclipse is wrong. I will cross check with javac.